# Sorting in mongo sharding environments degrades performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a query that performs something like this,

```rb
last_shipment_id = OrderDelivery.where(platform: 'business').desc(:shipment_id).limit(1).pluck(:shipment_id)[0]
```

It works great with only 1 ~ 5ms when I have correctly index with { platform: 1, shipment_id: -1 } without sharding environment in staging machine

However, our production is set up with 4 sharding mongo db, the result ends up in 1000 ~ 3000ms.

Does anyone know how this could happen or how might solve this case?

I've read about this slides https://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/how-queries-work-with-sharding

Well, it's said on slide 13, but still not sure it has mentioned how to solve the case though.

Comment: is the index present on your production servers?

Comment: yeah, sure~, also index on production

Comment: Did you split your data using `hashed` or `ranged` sharding ?

Comment: @felix ranged sharding~

Comment: can you confirm if indices satisfy the shard key specifications https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#shard-key-indexes

Comment: Not sure how this could be done? or checked?

Comment: Have you looked at the explain() output/can you post it?

Comment: What is your shard key ? Do all indexes include the shard key ? Can you run the query with explain option to verify if it querying single shard or multiple shard on mongos console ?

Comment: Here https://gist.github.com/berniechiu/2cf3757f0c8757b5fe86f5645e14c239

Comment: @Veeram wanna take a look?

Comment: Sure looks like something fishy is going on either on shard2 or shard3 - you didn't include the explain from those in the gist.  But since the number of documents examined on the one shard is quite low but total is super high, I'm guessing the right indexes are missing somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what your shard key is, but this query has to be scattered to all three shards, and that means if any of the shards are slow, the overall result will be slow.   In the gist you include explain for shard1 (which is fast) but omit it for shard2 and shard3 and overall numbers show that it's slow on one of those shards.

This means either the optimal index is not present on one of those shards, or there is a different index present that's being picked even though it's suboptimal.  The solution in the former case is to build all correct indexes, the solution in the second case is to use `hint` with the query to force the use of the correct index.